# How to remove a collection element without EntityManager#remove(...) in Doctrine 2?

Tags: collections, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one, doctrine-collection

I have a classical construction like `EntityA OneToMany EntityB`. Implemented as a bidirectional relationship:

- the `EntityB` has a property `$entityA` of type `EntityA` and
- the `EntityA` has a property `$entityBs`, that contains an `ArrayCollection` of `EntityB` elements.

Now I want to remove some `EntityB` elements. It would work like this:

```
$entityManager->remove($myEntityB);
$entityManager->flush();
```

But I'd like to be able just to "say" `$myEntityA->removeEntityB($entityB)` and not need to care about anything else. An advantage would be, that I can implement a method `EntityA#replaceEntityBs(ArrayCollection $entityBs)`, that simply removes all `EntityA#$entityBs` and replace them be the given elements.

**Is it possible / How to remove elements of a collection directly from the *inverse side* of a relationship (of course without to pass the `EntityManager` into the entity)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the reference to `EntityA` from the `EntityB` (first). In this case Doctrine will try to persist an `EntityB` without. But if we combine this with [`orphanRemoval=true`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal), we'll get the aimed result:

```
class EntityA
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $entityBs;
    ...
    public function removeEntityB(EntityB $entityB)
    {
        $this->entityBs->removeElement($entityB);
        $entityB->setEntityA(null);
        return $this;
    }
    ...
}

class EntityB
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var EntityA
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entityBs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_a_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $entityA;
    ...
    /**
     * @param EntityA $entityA
     * @return EntityB
     */
    public function setEntityA(EntityA $entityA = null)
    {
        $this->entityA = $entityA;
        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**Off topic: Replacing a collection**

Since I noted in the question, that an advantage would be, that one can implement a method like `EntityA#replaceEntityBs(ArrayCollection $entityBs)`, I want to share here a possible implementation.

The first naïve attempt was just to remove *all* `EntityBs` and then add (and persist) the new elements.

```
public function setEntityBs($entityBs)
{
    $this->removeEntityBs();
    $this->entityBs = new ArrayCollection([]);
    /** @var EntityB $entityB */
    foreach ($entityBs as $entityB) {
        $this->addEntityB($entityB);
    }
    return $this;
}
public function removeEntityBs()
{
    foreach ($this->getEntityBs() as $entityB) {
        $this->removeEntityB($entityB);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But if the input collection of the `setEntityBs(...)` contained existing `EntityBs` (that shold be updated), it led to deleting of them and only the new elements got persisted.

Here is a solution, that works as wished:

```
public function setEntityBs($entityBs)
{
    $this->removeEntityBsNotInList($entityBs);
    $this->entityBs = new ArrayCollection([]);
    /** @var EntityB $entityB */
    foreach ($entityBs as $entityB) {
        $this->addEntityB($entityB);
    }
    return $this;
}
private function removeEntityBsNotInList($entityBs)
{
    foreach ($this->getEntityBs() as $entityB) {
        if ($entityBs->indexOf($entityB) === false) {
            $this->removeEntityB($entityB);
        }
    }
}
```